# Convert MongoDB Schema generated using 8.0 driver version to 8.1 driver version

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, schema, obiee, mongo-driver

My environment has OBIEE 12c which uses the Progress DataDirect MongoDB driver. It uses the 8.0.2 driver to connect to MongoDB 4.4 version. The dB is upgraded to 7.0 version. As per Progress DataDirect's documentation, 8.1.0 driver should be used to connect MongoDB 7.0 version. I have installed and configured the driver as per the documentation. However, when I use the example application to connect to the dB, I am getting a General Error. Upon looking at the logs, the MongoDB Schema (schema.config) is getting automatically converted to 8.1.0 driver. This is expected as per the documentation.

The error however is "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "abc-xys-12n" when the new driver 8.1.0 is converting the table names created by the 8.0 driver.

How to fix this?

I have tried looking at every documentation available online. But no luck!